# How do I import stuff from sibling files in clojure/cider/nrepl?

Tags: clojure, classpath, cider, nrepl

I have a small project with `~/src/proj/{foo,bar}.clj` that I'm hacking on with emacs, cider and nREPL.  In `bar.clj` I do `(def base-13-joke 42)` and I want the code in `foo.clj` to refer to `bar.clj`'s `base-13-joke`. How do I do this?

---

My current classpath (with `~/src/proj` = `/jonas/src/mine/code/move-the-box`)

```
/home/jonas/src/mine/code/move-the-box/target/classes
/home/jonas/.m2/repository/cider/cider-nrepl/0.11.0/cider-nrepl-0.11.0.jar
/home/jonas/.m2/repository/org/tcrawley/dynapath/0.2.3/dynapath-0.2.3.jar
/home/jonas/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.nrepl/0.2.12/tools.nrepl-0.2.12.jar
/home/jonas/.m2/repository/clojure-complete/clojure-complete/0.2.4/clojure-complete-0.2.4.jar
/home/jonas/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.8.0/clojure-1.8.0.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar
```

I've tried `(add-classpath "file:///jonas/src/mine/code/move-the-box")` which appeared to have no effect, as well as `(cider.nrepl.middleware.util.java/add-classpath! "file:///home/jonas/src/mine/code/move-the-box")` which throws `IllegalArgumentException array element type mismatch  java.lang.reflect.Array.set (Array.java:-2)`. What's going on there?

Answer (score 4):

If you're working with multiple Clojure source files as a single project, you'll get a lot of mileage out of using a build tool like [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/) or [Boot](http://boot-clj.com/). For example, here's how you could create a simple Boot project called `myproject` with multiple source files.

First, create a `myproject` directory (it doesn't matter where) with these contents:

```
myproject
├── build.boot
└── src
    └── myproject
        ├── bar.clj
        └── foo.clj
```

Boot will run your `build.boot` file before it does anything else (e.g. running some of your code, creating a JAR, or starting a REPL). For now, all you need to tell Boot is that your source files will be in the `src` directory, so just add this line to `build.boot`:

```
(set-env! :source-paths #{"src"})
```

In `bar.clj`, put the definition that you want to access from your other code:

```
(ns myproject.bar)

(def base-13-joke 42)
```

Then, in `foo.clj`, you can reference `bar.clj` using a `:require` clause in your `ns` declaration:

```
(ns myproject.foo
  (:require [myproject.bar :as bar]))

(defn make-joke []
  (println (Long/toString bar/base-13-joke 13)))
```

And that's all there is to it! Of course, you probably want to actually *do* stuff with the code you've just written. Boot handles "doing things" through *tasks*. Let's write one that simply runs one of the functions in your project.

When you want to define a task to run with Boot, you can do so by adding the code to define that task to your `build.boot` file. First, though, since we're going to be calling some of our main code (in this case, the `make-joke` function in the `myproject.foo` namespace), we'll need to `require` that code. Add this line to `build.boot`:

```
(require '[myproject.foo :as foo])
```

Now we can define a simple `run` task (again, in `build.boot`) that will run our function:

```
(deftask run []
  (with-pass-thru _
    (foo/make-joke)))
```

The `with-pass-thru` business just has to do with some of the specifics of tasks in Boot, which you can read about in detail [here](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/Tasks).

Executing tasks is quite easy. Run this in the command line from your project root:

```
$ boot run
33
```

Boot also comes with some tasks built-in. For instance, if you run `boot repl`, you'll be presented with a familiar REPL prompt in the `boot.user` namespace:

```
boot.user=>
```

This namespace is the same one in which Boot executes the `build.boot` script, so since we have a `require` for `myproject.foo` in `build.boot`, we can use that namespace in the REPL:

```
boot.user=> (foo/make-joke)
33
nil
```

Of course, you can `require` other namespaces too:

```
boot.user=> (require '[myproject.bar :as bar])
nil
boot.user=> bar/base-13-joke
42
```

There's a whole lot more that you can do with Boot, like code reloading and interacting with CIDER, which you can read all about in the [Boot Wiki](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki).